# Delete node_modules folder recursively from a specified path using command line

Tags: bash, macos, command-line-interface, node-modules

I have multiple npm projects saved in a local directory. Now I want to take backup of my projects without the *[node_modules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63294260/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-node-modules-folder)* folder, as it is taking a lot of space and can also be retrieved any time using `npm install`.

So, what would be a solution to delete all *node_modules* folders recursively from a specified path using the command line interface?

Answer (score 779, accepted):

Print out a list of directories to be deleted:

```
find . -name 'node_modules' -type d -prune
```

Delete directories from the current working directory:

```
find . -name 'node_modules' -type d -prune -exec rm -rf '{}' +
```

---

Alternatively you can use [trash](https://github.com/sindresorhus/trash-cli) (`brew install trash`) for staged deletion:

```
find . -name node_modules -type d -prune -exec trash {} +
```

Comment: `-prune` is an important optimization. It'll case find not to recurse into `node_module` directories (to look for nested node_modules)

Comment: For a project, I get `/node_modules/gulp-server-livereload/node_modules: Directory not empty` in a lot of "inner" node_modules folders. How to workaround this?

Comment: This is like, I'm serious, the 20th time I am at this answer to copy this code... xD

Comment: What is the meaning of `'{}' +`?

Comment: `{}` is a placeholder which `find` replaces with the file path it found. `+` tells `find` to append all the file paths to a single command rather than running `rm` for each.

Comment: `find . -name 'node_modules' -type d -prune -exec du -chs {} + | grep t` to know the total size of what you are going to delete

Comment: Seeing `rm -rf` in amongst any copy and paste command line makes me shudder. If the script doesn't find anything, or find isn't installed in your version of unix, and you're executing from root of your hard drive, it could delete your whole hard drive. Very unlikely, but hey, worth mentioning.

Comment: @Cipi I went to upvote your comment, but I have noticed I have already upvoted it, probably years ago :).

Comment: Why all put `-f` for `rm` each time? It's useless almost forever and here as well

Comment: If you had a penny for every time I came to this post, You'd have enuff to buy some folks some fancy coffee on a given morning :)

Comment: Why not simply use `rm -rf node_modules **/node_modules`?

Comment: Actually the `trash` command of Sindre Sorhus you are referring to is installed bia `brew install macos-trash`. You might want to update either the link or the brew command to be in sync again. Anyway, great tip! So useful! Thanks.

Answer (score 283):

Try
https://github.com/voidcosmos/npkill

```
npx npkill
```

it will find all `node_modules` and let you remove them selectively.

[image: npkill]

Comment: A better option than above since I usually have 2-3 projects which I want to keep node_modules intact

Comment: This should be the top comment!

Comment: I prefer to nuke all folders and reinstall them again as needed. Who has time to pick and choose manually?

Comment: @fregante Me. I dont have the time to wait for 10+ package.jsons with pre and postscripts to finish. This takes a lot longer than to think 20s and choose 10s.

Comment: this is solid - was quick and with simple projects u just hit space right away and `node_modules` is sent to valhalla

Answer (score 111):

Improving on the accepted answer:

```
find . -name 'node_modules' -type d -prune -exec rm -rf '{}' +
```

I found that the command above would run a very long time to fetch all folders and then run a delete command. To make the command resumable, I'd suggest using `\;`. To see progress of the command being run, use `-print` to see the directory being deleted.

**Note:** You must first [cd](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cd_(command)) into the root directory and then run the command. Or instead of `find .`, use `find {project_directory}`.

To delete folders one by one:

```
find . -name 'node_modules' -type d -prune -exec rm -rf '{}' \;
```

To delete folders one by one and print the folder being deleted:

```
find . -name 'node_modules' -type d -prune -print -exec rm -rf '{}' \;
```

For the people who like an interactive way of doing this, refer to [jeckep's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58735855/10158227). Run this in the directory you wish to prune:

```
npx npkill
```

Comment: Nice improvements on the accepted answer @Sidharth, much appreciated

Comment: Good job @Sidharth

Comment: For (my own) future reference - I wanted to remove the contents of node_modules but leaving the directories in place (to add them to a Dropbox ignore list later). This works for me: `find . -name 'node_modules' -type d -prune -print -exec bash -c 'rm -rf "$0"/* "$0"/..?* "$0"/.[!.]*' {} \;` The wildcards are for matching hidden files and folders (starting with .) as per https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/77313/486273

Comment: Improving on this answer, using luminS ( https://github.com/wchang22/LuminS ) –

`find . -name 'node_modules' -type d -prune -exec lms rm '{}' +`

Comment: bruh! this does wonders

Answer (score 14):

When on Windows, I use the following `.BAT` file to delete `node_modules` recursively from the current folder:

```
@for /d /r . %d in (node_modules) do @if exist %d (echo %d && rd %d /s /q)
```

Or, via `CMD.EXE`:

```
>cmd.exe /c "@for /d /r . %d in (node_modules) do @if exist %d (echo "%d" && rd "%d" /s /q)""
```

Comment: The most recent version: https://gist.github.com/noseratio/6961e9c4d54741e01ca705e7ff1d0c80

Answer (score 13):

I have come across with this solution,

- first find the folder using `find` and specify name of the folder.
- execute delete command recursively `-exec rm -rf '{}' +`

run the following command to delete folders recursively

`find /path -type d -name "node_modules" -exec rm -rf '{}' +`

Answer (score 8):

In Bash, you can simply use

```
rm -rf node_modules **/node_modules
```

Answer (score 7):

`bash` function to remove `node_modules`. It will remove all `node_modules` directories recursively from the current working directory,
while printing found paths.

You just need to put in somewhere in your `$PATH`

```sh
rmnodemodules(){

  find . -name 'node_modules' -type d -prune -exec echo '{}' \; -exec rm -rf {} \; 

}
```

Answer (score 4):

Note: This is just improving on the accepted answer, please use the accepted answer first.

If you are so bored then keep reading.

Basically, this command should work fine for 99% of cases

`find . -name 'node_modules' -type d -prune -exec rm -rf '{}' +`

I notice that deleting files via the command line is longer than deleting a folder via Finder (when deleting from Finder it moves that folder to ~/.Trash directory).

So if you want to move node_modules to ~/.Trash folder then you can try

`find . -name 'node_modules' -type d -prune -exec sh -c 'mv -f "$1" "$(dirname "$1")/$(basename $(dirname "$1"))_$(basename "$1")" && mv "$(dirname "$1")/$(basename $(dirname "$1"))_$(basename "$1")" ~/.Trash/' sh {} \;`

as you notice it consist of 2 parts.

1. `find . -name 'node_modules' -type d -prune` find all node_module dirs
2. `-exec sh -c 'mv -f "$1" "$(dirname "$1")/$(basename $(dirname "$1"))_$(basename "$1")" && mv "$(dirname "$1")/$(basename $(dirname "$1"))_$(basename "$1")" ~/.Trash/' sh {} \;` rename node_module by prefixing it with it's parent folder name and move it to Trash

Before I had

```
~/Development/angular-projects
 ┣ project1
 ┣ project2
 ┗ project3
```

After running command

```
~/.Trash
 ┣ ~project1_node_modules
 ┣ ~project2_node_modules
 ┗ ~project3_node_modules
```

**Then make sure to empty trash**
[image]

**Or Turn On empty trash feature**
[image]

Answer (score 3):

If you want to move instead of delete it:

```
find . -name 'node_modules' -type d -prune -exec mkdir -p ./another/dir/{} \; -exec mv -i {} ./NODE_MODULES/{} \;
```

This will keep the directory structure.

Answer (score 3):

Quite late to the party, but doesn't this remove all node_modules recursively (on Linux and MacOS at least)?

```bash
rm -rf node_modules */node_modules */*/node_modules
```

Comment: It did not work

Comment: Try `rm -rf node_modules */node_modules **/node_modules`

Answer (score 2):

A simple trick to remove all [node_modules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63294260/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-node-modules-folder) folders in your servers (which can reduce a lot of space) is to run:

```
# For Ubuntu
sudo find / -not -path "/usr/lib/*" -name 'node_modules' -type d -prune -exec rm -rf '{}' +

# For macOS
sudo find / -not -path "/usr/local/*" -name 'node_modules' -type d -prune -exec rm -rf '{}' +
```

Here we need to exclude `/usr/lib/*` because if you won’t, it will delete your `npm` and you need to reinstall it :)

Answer (score 0):

Python Script to Delete the node_modules folder from multiple projects. Just place it in your project folder consisting multiple projects and run it.

```
import os
import shutil
dirname = '/root/Desktop/proj' #Your Full Path of Projects Folder
dirfiles = os.listdir(dirname)

fullpaths = map(lambda name: os.path.join(dirname, name), dirfiles)

dirs = []

for file in fullpaths:
    if os.path.isdir(file): dirs.append(file)

for i in dirs:
    dirfiles1 = os.listdir(i)
    fullpaths1 = map(lambda name: os.path.join(i, name), dirfiles1)
    dirs1 = []
    for file in fullpaths1:
        if os.path.isdir(file):
            dirs1.append(file)
            if(file[-12:]=='node_modules'):
                shutil.rmtree(file)
                print(file)
```

Comment: seems a bit overkill for something that can be done in one line from basic linux programs and probably even windows

Answer (score 0):

To expand on the previous answers:
Here is a script that automatically deletes all `*/node_modules` and `*/dist` folders to clean out any installed libraries.

```
#!/bin/bash
# Script to clean all:
#   - */node_modules
#   - */dist

scriptDir=$(cd -P -- "$(dirname -- "$0")" && pwd -P)
cd "$scriptDir"

echo "Removing node_modules..."
args=(
    . \( -name 'dist' -o -name 'node_modules' \)    # find all folders with name dist or node_modules
    -prune                                          # exclude recursive search in subdirectories
    -print                                          # output results
    -exec rm -rf '{}' +                             # delete all folders
)
find "${args[@]}"
echo "Done."
```

Comment: Not really an improvement from the decade old answers that were already given. Please, when answering old questions, be sure to bring something really new; for example some new ways of doing that did not exist back in the time.