# node_modules has too many files when using react framework

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, npm-install, node-modules

When I use react framework and I do a `npm install`, about 27,000 files are generated on my node_modules. The size is not the concern, rather, the amount of files. If I have to copy that directory somewhere else, it takes a very long time due to that many files. If I have to delete it, that takes long as well. My Google drive sync does not have an "exclude folder" option for node_modules, therefore, syncing that with cloud also takes a VERY long time. I also don't like the fact that each react project I have, will generate another 27,000 files.

Does anyone have a solution for this? Basically, I don't want 27,000 files for every react project I create. I was thinking of just having one GLOBAL node_modules somewhere and ALL react apps will call that instead of creating their own node_modules folder.

Here is my package.json

```
{
  "name": "react-typescript-tutorial",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.18.0",
    "enzyme": "^3.3.0",
    "react": "^16.4.1",
    "react-bootstrap": "^0.32.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.4.1",
    "react-redux": "^5.0.2",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.3.1",
    "react-router-redux": "^5.0.0-alpha.9",
    "redux": "^4.0.0",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts-ts start",
    "build": "react-scripts-ts build",
    "test": "react-scripts-ts test --env=jsdom",
    "eject": "react-scripts-ts eject"
  }
}
```

P.S. I'm willing to change to a different package manager like yarn or whatever, if it can generate less files.

Comment: Are you storing your projects in Google Drive? I recommend using e.g. GitHub instead, and using a `.gitignore` file with `node_modules` in it.

Comment: We use TFS on our main projects. This is just an example I guess. Also, when we do things like backup hard drives, it takes a lot longer with so many files.

Comment: No. Those files are dependencies, and as such will be required no matter what package manager you use. The most you can do is "ignore" said folder in the sync/backup/whatever tools you use. If they don't have such support... use another tool... or don't use react

Comment: Ah, I see. I don't know if you can store all dependencies in one place for every project, but it might be worth using a [script like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42950501/delete-node-modules-folder-recursively-from-a-specified-path-using-command-line#answer-43561012) before backup.

Comment: Thanks @Tholle, that helps a bit for sure. Also, I'm not sure why this is being downvoted so much, obviously it is a concern to some people for various reason if posts like that exists in the first place.

Answer (score 4):

I agree, it's ridiculous how many files they make. It would be better if they wouldn't write just ten lines in a new file. I think the structure is not very robust. And the poor file system have to make all these files. Luckily I don't use hard drives anymore, but still it takes much longer time with many files.

edit: So I just checked my react ++ mobx, +decorators project, and it had node_modules folder for a small project for duplicate files. It had 16000 duplicate files, with the possibility to clean 150MB of 280MB. I think that's just absurdly unnecessary. Proboble multiple versions for each dependency when they could have just used the same.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

1. Install all of your dependencies in global.
2. Go to each module of it (just module in dependencies ) and run `npm link` you registed that module.
3. Go to your project and run `npm link <name module need link>`
4. Done, npm created link to your dependencies

I don't Google drive sync it or not, but npm don't need install it.

You can try  [Exclude folder in Folder](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/drive/cygkCian8JI)  or 
[Exclude subfolder from sync, but keep this folder in PC](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/drive/zRU34aolkdo)

Or you don't use `npm install` to install module.
You should install global for all and set enviroment variable `NODE_PATH` to global node_modules.
When require, node will call it.

Answer (score 1):

I'm considering learning something else.

Elm sounds promising for organized and tidy filesystem.
And googles polymer-project aim to change the web into not needing any framework at all.