# print the commands to delete node_modules folders recursively in a bash text file

Tags: bash, macos, command-line, command-line-interface, node-modules

I want this - https://stackoverflow.com/a/43561012/126833

`find . -name 'node_modules' -type d -prune -exec rm -rf '{}'`

except - instead of getting this done automatically, I want the all of the `rm -rf /path/to/project/node_modules` commands in a bash file like rm_node_modules.sh for me to review and then only I'll execute as `bash rm_node_modules.sh`

So basically my `rm_node_modules.sh` should be like :

```
rm -rf /path/to/project-1/node_modules
rm -rf /path/to/project-2/node_modules
rm -rf /path/to/project-3/node_modules
```

Comment: It is hard to understand your question.  Are you asking how to put the `find` command in a shell script?  Or how to hardcode a bunch of `rm`s into a shell script?

Comment: I want the above `rm_node_modules.sh` file generated for a folder that contains node_modules. I can write code in python or php to look for node_modules in a folder and print the rm command for each folder - I was just wondering if there's a one-liner bash command do achieve this.

Comment: Can you try `... -exec echo rm -rf '{}' > rm_node_modules.sh` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are on macOS where `find` [does not support the `-printf` flag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/752818/find-lacks-the-option-printf-now-what) which would make this a bit simpler.  But something like this will do the job:

```
find . -name node_modules -type d -print0 | xargs -0 stat -f "rm -rf %N" > rm_node_modules.sh
```

Comment: Thanks for the one-liner. I somehow dread the idea of an automatic `rm -rf` command. I'm afraid of a catastrophe.

Comment: Yes, fair enough. You can make it interactive, so you have to confirm each one, by using `rm -rfi`.

Comment: I ran your command in my workspace folder and the bash file has 116 rm commands. So that would be a lot of ENTERs. I thought I would manually glace through the parent folders and decide in case there are any I dont want deleted.